# What is the difference between ~A(){} and ~A() throw(){} where A is a class name?

Tags: c++, exception, c++17, c++14

What is the difference between `~A(){}` and `~A() throw(){}` where `A` is a class name.

What is the use of having `throw()` for a destructor?

Comment: the latter is deprecated/removed (c++11/17). https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec.

Answer (score 2):

In the old days it was valid to throw exceptions out of destructors and nothing bad would happen (unless an exception is already propagating).

In modern C++ destructors are noexcept by default (so exceptions cause application termination).

So your code is for an old C++ code base (as throw is depreciated in favor of `noexcept`).

What it is trying to tell you is that the destructor does not throw exceptions (and if for some reason an exception was not intercepted the program would be terminated (rather than let the exception escape the destructo)).

Note there is a subtle difference between `throw()` and `noexcept`.

The `throw()` still guarantees that a throw exception inside the destructor will unwind the stack all the way to this destructor. If the exception tries to escape the destructor the application is terminated.

A `noexcept` it is implementation defined if the stack is unwound or the application is simply terminated if the exception could escape the destructor.

Since your destructor has no actual code in the body. Your exceptions would have to come from the destructor of one of the members of `A`.